# React 18: State update inside useEffect is postponed if there is also state update inside useLayoutEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-18

## In React 18

If we have `useLayoutEffect` and `useEffect` in a component and both of them update component's state then `useEffect` updates will be postponed until `useLayoutEffect` stops triggering renders.

Example

```
export const App = () => {
  const [done, setDone] = useState(false);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (counter < 20) {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
  }); // intentionally run on every render

  useEffect(() => {
    setDone(true);
  }); // intentionally run on every render

  console.log("render done", done);
  console.log("render counter", counter);
  console.log("\n");

  return <div>{counter} renders</div>;
};
```

Gives an output of

```
render done false
render counter 0
 
render done false
render counter 1

render done false
render counter 2

...

render done false
render counter 20

render done true
render counter 20
```

`done` state is updated only after we stop triggering render inside `useLayoutEffect`.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Andronomewalka/rec_render

GitHub repo: https://github.com/Andronomewalka/rec_render

## In React 17

Provided code results in

```
render done false
render counter 0

render done true
render counter 1
...
```

So state update from `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` applied at the same render.

I found a similar problem with [useSyncExternalStore](https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore) in [Bug: setState inside useEffect is unreliable in React 18 #25593](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25593) thread.

**My question is**: Does this happen in React 18 because the code inside `useLayoutEffect` and all state updates scheduled from it block the browser from repainting the screen and at the same time the state updates inside `useEffect` are processed after browser repaint the screen ?

So in that way updates from `useLayoutEffect` delays `useEffect` updates ?

And in React 17 it worked another way ?

https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect#caveats
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#caveats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr;** The reason the `done` state is not updated until after the `useLayoutEffect` is  finished is because in most cases `useEffect()` runs *after the screen as been rendered (painted)* and `useLayoutEffect()` blocks that.

A fair question from @TusharShahi in comments -  [This post](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) should clarify the changes in 18. One would use `flushSync()` to force re-renders. Please note that everywhere in the docs suggests to avoid this technique for performance reasons. For simple things it would be fine.

**Details:**

From the [`useLayoutEffect` Docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect#caveats):

> The code inside `useLayoutEffect` and all state updates scheduled from
> it block the browser from repainting the screen.

Additional clarification comes from the examples on that page.

From [**useLayoutEffect vs useEffect** Example 1](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect#measuring-layout-before-the-browser-repaints-the-screen):

> React guarantees that the code inside `useLayoutEffect` and any state
> updates scheduled inside it will be processed before the browser
> repaints the screen.

Here is [what the docs say](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#caveats) about `useEffect()`:

> If your Effect wasn’t caused by an interaction (like a click), React
> will let the browser paint the updated screen first before running
> your Effect. If your Effect is doing something visual (for example,
> positioning a tooltip), and the delay is noticeable (for example, it
> flickers), you need to replace useEffect with useLayoutEffect.
>
> Even if your Effect was caused by an interaction (like a click), the
> browser may repaint the screen before processing the state updates
> inside your Effect. Usually, that’s what you want. However, if you
> must block the browser from repainting the screen, you need to replace
> useEffect with useLayoutEffect.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I was assuming about that, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: But how does this explain the difference in behaviour b/w 18 and 17

Comment: @TusharShahi - Fair question. [This post](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) should clarify the changes in 18. One would use `flushSync()` to force re-renders. Please note that everywhere in the docs suggests to avoid this technique for performance reasons. For simple things it would be fine.

Comment: @TusharShahi - to be clear, I was answering the OPs direct question near the end of the Q that starts with **My question is:**.

Comment: @TusharShahi - edited answer to address your question and my followup.